# TFS builds: failed to do "Get" for random files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

First of all, we are using TFS 2013 update 3, and the whole system worked well before today's  issue.

Today, both of our 2 TFS build agents failed to do successful TFS builds anymore.

I checked the build log, and found the build process failed at the very first step, CoreGet, like below

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(895,5,895,5): error : One or more errors occurred while performing a Get operation

What’s interesting is, it’s not failed to get every file, but just failed to get some files;
What’s more interesting is, the fail-to-get-file-list is not fixed.

In my project, there are more than 10,000 files, and every time, **12** of them is failed to be got, but the files in the 12 are randomly picked (at least I did not find any pattern).The error message for any file is like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(895,5,895,5): error : C:\Builds\6\NameOfMyFile: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I checked the local path of build agent, and actually all these files are successfully fetched from TFS server and saved to build agent.

Any ideas what happens?

Comment: Could it be the file path is to long?

Comment: when you say `I checked the local path of build agent, and actually all these files are successfully fetched from TFS server and saved to build agent.` do you mean that the files are actually there and for some reason the build just can't see them?

Comment: @Wouter, yes I thought about that, but since the failed files are not fixed, so I think the possibility is small.

Comment: @Just TFS, yes, you are correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you check the free disk space available on the TFS Server? I got a similar error trying to retrieve files from TFS and it turns out that the disk was full. Clearing up some space fixed it.

This is the full error I got from Visual Studio, for reference:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Error Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Ryan, seems it really is a disk space problem (C drive is full).

Comment: Thanks Ryan, after creating space on TFS server, this message is gone.